# What does the `+1` in `mov BX, offset varName+1` do?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Let's say I defined a variable `varName dw 50`. As the title implies, I'm quite confused as what `mov BX, offset varName+1` does. I somewhat understand that you're trying to access the address of `varName`, but I don't get what's `varName+1` for, given I input a string to `varName`.

Comment: `varName+1` is the address of `varName` plus one, i.e. the address of the second byte of `varName`.

Comment: So if the address of `varName` is 80H, then it's 81H? What value does it concern technically? Thank you for the reply, by the way!

Comment: Yes, if `varName` is at address `80h`, then `varName+1` is address `81h`.  What is “What value does it concern technically” supposed to mean?

Comment: Are there any implications for it? For example, does it mean to take another memory space because of the `+1` or it's just to get another location? Sorry for the questions, I'm new to assembly language, and I'm still studying the basics.

Comment: Recall: addresses are just numbers.  You can do arithmetic on them.  There are no magical implications from that.  It's just the address of `varName` with 1 added to it.  There's nothing special about that.